How to enable Geany hunspell spellchecker
I'm using Geany 1.38 on MX Linux 23, I have Hunspell & plugin installed and the English dictionary is working, but when I tried to add Spanish dictionary, it seems not working (Spanish text still shows red underline), I've added the files (index.aff & index.dic from here, and also tried to install using this command sudo apt install hunspell-es in my terminal, still the same problem). What am I missing?
